# culture doesn't change when I set culture cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I set the ".AspNetCore.Culture" cookie to nb-NO, but the current culture are always en-US.

Startup, ConfigureServices:
**services.AddLocalization(options)**;

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(options)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(Const.DefaultCompatibilityVersion);
```

**Startup, Configure**:

```
builder.UseLCAssetsLocalization(opt => 
{
    opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(Const.LocalizationDefaultCulture);
    opt.SupportedCultures = Const.LocalizationDefaultSupportedCultures.ToList();
    opt.SupportedUICultures = Const.LocalizationDefaultSupportedCultures.ToList();
});

public static IApplicationBuilder UseLCAssetsLocalization(this IApplicationBuilder builder, Action<RequestLocalizationOptions> options)
{
    builder.UseStaticFiles();

    RequestLocalizationOptions opts = new RequestLocalizationOptions();
    options.Invoke(opts);

    return builder.UseRequestLocalization(opts);
}
```

**Const.LocalizationDefaultCulture**: nb-NO

**appsettings**:

```
"LC.Assets": {
"SiteId": 8,
"Language": "nb-NO"
}
```

Am I missing something??